# Batch file Copy Folder specified in a .txt file

Tags: text, batch-file, copy, directory

I'm looking for batch file code that will copy folders specified in a text file.
So in the text file

C:\User\
C:\Random\Random\Random
and so on.
The destination will be set at N:\Backups\PC

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? what problems you found? to get you started, read HELP FOR, or see stackoverflow.com/questions/9143018/batch-copy-files-from-txt-file-into-one-folder

Comment: thanks i solved it using     SET destfolder=N:\PC
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (copy.txt) DO XCOPY /I /S /Y "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set dest=N:\Backups\PC
for /f %%i in (C:\dirs.txt) do copy "%%i" %dest%
```