# Batch file to copy folder and files specified in a .text file

Tags: batch-file

Please help me with a Batch Code:

I want to copy all the folders and files as specified in  a .txt file.

My code is as :

```
 @ECHO OFF
SET "DEST_DIR=D:\Sarvesh\Target"
SET "SEARCH_DIR=D:\Sarvesh\harshad"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (D:\Sarvesh\C23799.txt) DO (
FOR /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%f IN (%%a) DO (xcopy /S /I "%%~f" "%DEST_DIR%" 2> NUL)
)
```

but it's not working ...error 0 files copied..

Comment: remove the `@echo off` and the `2>nul` to see errormessages. Also: `for /R` and `xcopy /s` - why doing the recursion two times?

Comment: Maybe you need `('type D:\Sarvesh\c23799.txt')` for the first 'for'

Comment: Hi Stephan thanks for your reply..

Comment: Can You please provide me the coding of the "batch file to copy folder and files which are specified in my text file"

Comment: # Marichyasana  The specified text file is already defined .. My files and folders are not getting copied to the destiantion :(

Comment: @AnonCode, can you please update your question with an example of what is in your text file.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11190176/2152082)

Comment: Does D:\Sarvesh\Target\FOTS/CONFIG_CREATOR/src/N2N_Config/conf/util-reflector.conf specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? D
0 File(s) copied

Comment: I am getting this error... and no files are getting copied. The batch code is reading the path but not copying anything..popup with above mentioned error.

Comment: My Code is as follow :               @ECHO OFF 
for /f "delims=" %%i in (D:\Sarvesh\C23799.txt) do echo D|xcopy "D:\Sarvesh\harshad\%%i" "D:\Sarvesh\Target\%%i" /i /z /y